# Import & display csv data into html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, jquery-csv

I am trying to load my CSV data in HTML tables dynamically/on page reload.
My data is of two types :

csv1 :

```
Host,% Time alive,% Time available,Total
server1.test.com,100.0%,100.0%,100.0%
server2.test.com,100.0%,100.0%,100.0%
server3.test.com,100.0%,100.0%,100.0%
```

csv2:

```
name;age;address;id;natureXYZ.;jennie;23;chicago;12345;good;Jhon;23;Boston;12367;good;
```

I am using this [plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-CSV-File-Into-Data-Table.html) code to parse it and display in my html page.

but it doesn't works,I am pretty new to this, is there anything I need to change here? what I understand is delimiter might be a problem but i dont know what to place here according to my CSV data.

```
  <script>
  init_table({
  csv_path: 'data/data1.csv', 
  element: 'table-container', 
  allow_download: true,
  csv_options: {separator: ',', delimter:'"'},
  datatables_options: {"paging": false}
  </script>
```

Comment: your csv is working with the last version of this plugin located in github
https://github.com/derekeder/csv-to-html-table

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez thanks for the response, can you please show it in JSfiddle ? as i have tried it already.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/_j_gonzalez/cuqdu6Lk/4/

Comment: Do i need to keep the CSV file in a server path?
i doubt that it parses csv data from local

Comment: I am not able to get the table I dont know what went wrong.It doesn't display any data

Comment: I cloned the github repo that I mentioned earlier and ran the example and your data by starting a web server on that directory.

Comment: thanks Jorge Gonzalez
I too did the same and it worked but I don't have sorting options and search options as you have shown here & also same in github.
 jsfiddle.net/_j_gonzalez/cuqdu6Lk/4
And for my second type of csv data that is seperated by --> ; (semicolon) that doesn't display any data.

Comment: Yes, I think that the second data could be transformed

Comment: I have tried changing the delimiter in CSV optionsof the javascript, but it did not worked.

Comment: A csv table is supposed to have columns and rows, represented in the first data by the commas and new lines, but in the second data there is only one line separated by semicolons, because of that the jquery-csv pluging is not able to handle the second one.  Can you change the format of your csv file in the server?

Comment: I will try to do that and check.
in place of semicolon I can place it with comma seperated values

Comment: Thanks Jorge , it works but only issue is the external resource bootstrap.min.css I have the same CSS file in my page where I am trying to place this code.
but this is overlapping and doesn't show any data.
Also when I am loading 5 mb data it is too slow to handle can this not handle a big CSV file?